# How to sort only displayed rows in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with paging, which displays 5 records in each page.

How can I sort the elements of the current page only?

And other pages should not be sort?

I am using ASP.NET and C#.NET.

Is there any way to do this in LINQ?

Thank You.

Comment: It would help if you at least told us what programming language you were using. I'm sure Gridview exists in more than one. The more context you can give, the better your chances of getting a useful response.

Comment: What language/platform/framework are you using ? Plase provide details.

Comment: I'm gonna stab a guess at ASP.NET, and maybe guess the code-behind as VB.NET?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET and C#.NET.
And the other pages should not be sort.

Comment: @Kapil123: StackOverflow works like a Wiki. That means that you (and everyone else) are allowed to edit your question. It's best to give additional information like the programming language in the question and tags directly so that everybody can see it immediately.

Comment: More info is clearly better, but it is completely irrelevant what the server side language is in this case, since this is a client-side solution

Comment: @Keith Rousseau: The solution does not necessarily need to be client-side. And that this is in a Web context hasn't been clear from the original question either.

Comment: @divo - Any good solution would be client-side. Pointless postbacks are certainly a hallmark of WebForms development, but any good solution tries to minimize server traffic - it's slower, uses more bandwidth and less scalable.

Comment: Could any one please answer this question

Comment: @Kapil - I already answered the question. Use a javascript library to do it. There are tons out there. You shouldn't be posting back to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use a client-side library if you just want to sort what is displayed. Here is an example of one in jQuery: http://tablesorter.com/docs/.
There are tons of them out there - just do a bit of Googling. At that point it doesn't matter what server side language you use (although my guess is ASP.NET)

Comment: Another jQuery plugin example: I've been using DataTables (http://www.datatables.net) recently. Take a look.