# sort every group of size n

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sort every group of size N entries out of K entries where N

e.g. lets say we have table

```
Student 
(
   StudentID int, 
   StudentName varchar(50), 
   DepartmentName varchar(50), 
   Marks float
)
```

and it has 100  entries I want sort every 10 entries with specific criterion lets say by Marks ascending.

e.g. Consider the following data

```
StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
1            A             CS             98.7 
2            B             IT              96.78 
3            C             Civil           95.67 
4            D             Electronics      93.25
```

I have grid and it has paging mechanism. If I set pageSize = 2 then on page 1 the data will be

```
StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
1            A             CS             98.7 
2            B             IT              96.78
```

On page 2 the data will be

```
StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
3            C             Civil           95.67 
4            D             Electronics      93.25
```

If I sort my grid by order of StudentName DESC then the whole data get sorted and for page 1 my data will be

```
 StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
4            D             Electronics      93.25 
3            C             Civil           95.67
```

and on page 2 the data will be

```
 StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
2            B             IT              96.78 
1            A             CS             98.7
```

Instead of it, the expected output will be like this on page 1

```
StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
2            B             IT              96.78 
1            A             CS             98.7
```

and on page 2 will be

```
StudentID  StudentName  Departmentname  Marks 
4            D             Electronics      93.25 
3            C             Civil           95.67
```

That's why I want to sort the data of size 2 here specifically instead of sorting whole data.

In general let say we have 100 entries in total and want to sort every 10 entries then row no. 13 after applying sorting its row number should lie in row no. 11 to row no. 20

Comment: How about adding example data and expected output? :)

Comment: On what basis you are ordering 100 entries? because when you say sort every 10 entries all the 100 records must be ordered on some column. Then we can order every 10 records by some other specific criterion (like Marks)

Comment: hard to say without data, but have a look at [NTILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx)

Comment: @juergend I just provide the data

Comment: @KishoreKumar Exactly for example I have 100 entries in total and want to sort every 10 entries then entry no. 13 after applying sorting its row number should lie in row no. 11 to row no. 20

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean by " I want sort every 10 entries with specific criterion". You sample output seems that you just need to use the `ORDER BY` statement.

Comment: [How can I sort the elements of the current page only ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409153/how-to-sort-only-displayed-rows-in-gridview) is this what you are looking for ??

Comment: @CoderofCode exactly the sorting operation should operate on page wise and not as whole, If I sort whole data the paging elements gets changed.

Comment: @blckbird If I used simply 'order by' then the original elements on specific page will get changed. I shown this by example in the question itself.

Comment: Do you want to sort the data on the grid after binding to the grid or at the sql server ?

Comment: @CoderofCode at the sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Sample data orderdered by Marks DESC**

```
StudentID   StudentName DepartmentName  Marks
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------------------
1           A           CS              98.7
2           B           IT              96.78
3           C           Civil           95.67
4           D           Electronics     93.25
```

**SOLUTION**

```
DECLARE @pagSize INT = 2
DECLARE @pageNumber INT = 1 --Page you want to sort

;WITH SortByMarks AS( --Sorted first by Marks DESC
    SELECT 
        *, 
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Marks DESC),
        pageNumber = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Marks DESC) - 1)/@pagSize + 1
    FROM Student
)
SELECT
    StudentId,
    StudentName,
    DepartmentName,
    Marks
FROM SortByMarks
WHERE
    pageNumber = @pageNumber
ORDER BY StudentName DESC
```

**RESULT**

```
StudentId   StudentName DepartmentName  Marks
----------- ----------- --------------- ----------------------
2           B           IT              96.78
1           A           CS              98.7
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question properly...In oracle this is how it happens

select STUDENT_ID (select * from STUDENTS order by STUDENT_MARKS asc) where ROWNUM<=10
minus 
select STUDENT_ID (select * from STUDENTS order by STUDENT_MARKS asc) where ROWNUM<=1

here we are ordering marks in ascending order then fetching first nine rows except first row.
If its not what you are looking for then then explain the question little more

Comment: The thing is we need to sort the group of data  of size N rows, so user can choose any group, for example we 100 records in total and let our group size is 10 , after applying the sort operation the position of elements within the group should be remain, e.g. row no 13 after sorting operation should lie in group no. 2 (as group no 1 of row no. 1 to 10 and 2nd group consist of row index 11 to 20 inclusively  )and it's new row no. should lie in 11 to 20 inclusively,

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

--This is for ordering every 2 records on Marks

```
SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY (Row1 + 1) / 2 ORDER BY C2
    ) Row2
FROM (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY C1 DESC
        ) Row1
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS ID
        ,'A' AS C1
        ,98.7 AS C2

    UNION

    SELECT 2 AS ID
        ,'B' AS C1
        ,96.78 AS C2

    UNION

    SELECT 3 AS ID
        ,'C' AS C1
        ,95.67 AS C2

    UNION

    SELECT 4 AS ID
        ,'D' AS C1
        ,93.25 AS C2
    ) T
) T1;
```

For ORdering 10 records, Below is the Query :

```
SELECT *
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY (Row1 + 1) / 10 ORDER BY C2
    ) Row2
FROM (
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY C1 DESC
        ) Row1
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS ID
        ,'A' AS C1
        ,98.7 AS C2

    UNION

    SELECT 2 AS ID
        ,'B' AS C1
        ,96.78 AS C2

    UNION

    SELECT 3 AS ID
        ,'C' AS C1
        ,95.67 AS C2

    UNION

    SELECT 4 AS ID
        ,'D' AS C1
        ,93.25 AS C2
    ) T
) T1;
```

Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Will you please suggest a generalize solution since my application got dynamic data of large size.

Answer (score 0):

Same Mahesh,
Let assume user hit on page 2.
So now my input for rownum would be 2*10 and for other rownum my input would be (2-1)*10, and that would give u next 10 10 data according to pagination selected.

so You just need to capture page number of pagination in your program and give that as an input.

`select STUDENT_ID (select * from STUDENTS order by STUDENT_MARKS asc) where ROWNUM<=[$pageRequest]*10 
minus 
select STUDENT_ID (select * from STUDENTS order by STUDENT_MARKS asc) where ROWNUM<=([$pageRequest] -1)*20`